# Efficiently sorting through a generator of paths in order to find the longest one

Tags: python, list, sorting, networkx, graph-theory

I am trying to write a function that calculates the maximum number of unexplored cells in a grid that is reachable within a given fuel limit. For example I have a 10x10 grid, and each cell in the grid is connected to each other and their weight is the Manhattan distance between them. From this grid I create an adjacency matrix whose dimensions are then 100x100, and create a graph from the adjacency matrix using the networkx library. I then use the all_simple_paths function which returns a generator that contains all the paths from a source to a target node.

Now comes the problem, when trying to sort through this generator in order to find the path that contains the most unexplored cells (in this case just equal to the path length), my program either runs out of memory, or it takes a really long time to execute.

I have tried to convert the generator into a list, and then sort the list from longest to shortest path length, but this just causes the python script to keep growing in memory size until it takes all available memory on my PC (16GB). I have also tried using the sorted function to sort the generator as below, but this just takes too long to execute, and eventually runs out of memory as well.

```
G = nx.from_numpy_array(A)
sorted_paths = sorted(nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=current_node, target=target_node), key=len, reverse=True)
```

If anybody has any suggestions as to how I can tackle my problem, it would be greatly appreciated. Whether it be sorting the generator, or maybe another function inside networkx/another python library that could help me find the max number of unexplored cells in a grid.

Comment: If you want max, why do you sort?

Comment: First of all as @nocomment said, if you are just looking for the max then why are you even sorting them. second, I'm guessing what takes so much memory is not the sorting of already existing paths, but the creation of those paths. navigational algorithms can be very complicated and finding the fastest path is rarely easy. Now if that's your problem creating a good path finding algorithm is the solution, it's a whole other topic. You can easily find some great ones online, but one that worked great for me is "A*". Cheers (;

Comment: @Jonathan, I was sorting them to try and speed up finding the biggest path, as I need to not just simply find the max, but the max that also stays below a fuel limit. I tried just using a loop to go through them and do this, but it was taking a very long time, maybe I implemented this incorrectly though. 

The creation of the paths is not taking up that much memory as the result is stored in a generator. I have written my own reward based A* algorithm, this function is a part of the larger algorithm as I need to estimate how many unexplored cells I can reach from a certain cell.

Comment: @AltusCilliers I still dont see how then if you already have the paths. sorting them over a specific property would take so much memory. Why don't you count their lengths *While* making them. and add their length as a property in whatever class you use to store them. then sort them by that property. ALSO, from what I read, you still don't need to sort them at all. All you need is to go through them all and have this: if (this.length > maxLength && this.FuelConsumption < fuelLimit) {var bestPath = this}

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comments above, I would search on the grid graph itself instead of searching on the graph of Manhattan distances.

1. The grid-graph is much smaller than the graph of Manhattan distances, and hence the search space of possible paths is smaller.
2. Paths with increments of 1 grid position will always be at least as optimal as paths that "jump" over a grid position.
3. Using the grid-graph, further optimisations become apparent. For example, iff the Manhattan distance between A and B is even, one need only consider paths of even maximum length. Say the distance between A and B is 10, and the maximum path length is 15. Then one only needs to look at paths of maximum length 14, as there will be no path of length 15 between A and B. This easily translates to another speedup of factor 2.

```py
import networkx as nx
import time

g = nx.grid_2d_graph(10, 10)

for maximum_distance in range(17, 21):
    tic = time.time()
    paths = list(nx.all_simple_paths(g, (0, 0), (9, 9), maximum_distance))
    toc = time.time()
    print(f"Maximum distance: {maximum_distance}; total paths: {len(paths)}; time elapsed: {toc-tic:.1f} seconds")

# Maximum distance: 17; total paths: 0; time elapsed: 25.8 seconds
# Maximum distance: 18; total paths: 48620; time elapsed: 62.9 seconds
# Maximum distance: 19; total paths: 48620; time elapsed: 178.0 seconds
# Maximum distance: 20; total paths: 621452; time elapsed: 462.2 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately these times would still be too slow for the purpose I want to use it for, and if I was to use my original 2D grid, it would be much larger than the graph I was planning to use. I think trying to find all the possible paths and then sorting them to try find the max length is just not efficient enough for the application I want to use it in. I have changed strategy and am no longer trying to use this method